# Search View doesn't filter ListView data with setOnQueryTextListener

Tags: android, mysql, database, listview, searchview

My search view not working in android app, in my list view data come from mysql database. When use `setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()` on my search view object. filter not working.

```
public class Students extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    SearchView mySearachView;
    StudentAdapter studentAdapter;
    public static ArrayList<Student_Model> studentModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    String url = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/androidStudentArrayList";
    Student_Model student_model;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_students);
        mySearachView = (SearchView)findViewById(R.id.search_student);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.student_list_view);
        studentAdapter = new StudentAdapter(this, studentModelArrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(studentAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
                ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(view.getContext());
                CharSequence[] dialogItem = { "See Details"," Update Student Details" , "Update Image"};
                builder.setTitle(studentModelArrayList.get(position).getName());
                builder.setItems(dialogItem, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                        switch (i){
                            case 0:
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),StudentDetails.class).putExtra("position", position));
                              break;
                            case 1:
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Student_Edit.class).putExtra("position", position));
                              break;
                            case 2:
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Student_Image_Update.class).putExtra("position", position));
                                break;
                        }}});
                builder.create().show();}
        });

        retrieveData();

        mySearachView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                studentAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                return false;
            }
        });  
    }

    public  void retrieveData(){
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                studentModelArrayList.clear();
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                    if(success.equals("1")){
                        for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String img;
                            String image = object.getString("img");
                            if(image.equals("")){
                                img = "https://blueboyscricket.com/img/android_placeholder.png";
                            }else{
                                img = "https://blueboyscricket.com/images/"+image;
                            }
                            String id = object.getString("id");
                            String name = object.getString("cnd_name");
                            String father_name = object.getString("father_name");
                            String mobile_no = object.getString("contact_no_primary");
                            String doj = object.getString("doj");
                            String mother_name = object.getString("mother_name");
                            String dob = object.getString("dob");
                            String status = object.getString("status");
                            student_model = new Student_Model(id,name,father_name,doj,mobile_no,img,status,mother_name,dob);
                            studentModelArrayList.add(student_model);
                            studentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }else{}

                } catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(Students.this, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to do `studentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after  `studentAdapter.getFilter().filter(s)`

Comment: Thanks for Reply, But its not Working

Comment: Please provide the code of `StudentAdapter`